# No Business Data Connectivity Service associated with current web context error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-deployment

I am running on a new dev setup for SharePoint 2010 and trying to setup some External Content types.  I think that I have setup BCS correctly (since I see it running in the central administration).  When I go into SharePoint designer 2010 and try to setup a new External Content Type, I get the following error:

"There is no Business Connectivity Service associated with the current web context."

Am I missing something with the configuration or why am I not able to setup a new External Content Type to point to my existing SQL database

Answer (score 7):

The service might be running but make sure that you have associated the service with your Web Application. Go to Central Admin > Manage Web Applications > Select the Web Application > Click Service Connections in the Ribbon. In the dialog make sure that the BDC Service is checked.